# Singular values of $A+kI$ when A is symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I recently asked about the $\sigma_i(A+kI)$ for a generic matrix $A$ and found I had the wrong identity in mind. I was playing around and I got some confusing work trying to prove the property with the assumption that A is symmetric.

So $\sigma_i(A) = \sqrt{\lambda_i(A^TA)}$, $A':= A+kI$ therefore $\sigma_i(A') = \sqrt{\lambda_i(A'^TA')}.$

We see that $A'^TA'=(A+kI)^T(A+kI) = A^TA + kA^T+kA+k^2I $

Using the symmetry of $A$, we get that $A'^TA'= A^2 +2kA+k^2I $

Consider $v$ such that $ Av = \lambda_iv$

Then $A'^TA'v = (A^2 +2kA+k^2I)v = (\lambda_i^2 + 2k\lambda_i +k^2)v = (\lambda_i+k)^2v$

So its the case that, $\lambda_i(A'^TA') = (\lambda_i(A)+k)^2$, therefore $\sigma_i(A') = \lambda_i(A) + k$

What I find confusing about this result is this would mean the singular values of the $A+kI$ matrix are the same as its eigenvalues? I'm assuming this has to do with the fact that $A+kI$ is symmetric since $A$ is, though I haven't heard about this property of symmetric matrices. I was considering a possible reason why this second property could be correct to be that if A is symmetric:

$Q\Lambda Q^T = A = U \Sigma V^T$ Since $Q,V,$ and $U$ are orthonormal we can do:

$U,V := Q$ which means $ \Sigma = \Lambda$

Is any of this correct at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling gives for symmetric $A$ that the singular values are the absolute values of the eigenvalues.

So except for the absolute value - when you take the root only the nonnegative solution is valid - you got it right.

For $U,V$: You can set them to $Q$ initially and then put a few negative signs in one of them, say $U$, to correct for those eigenvalues of $A$ that are negative.